# How can I convert a possible pieces' moves to an actual move in a bitboard?

Tags: engines, programming, bitboard

If I have a bitboard (e.g. for knight squares he can move to) like this:

```
00000000
00000000
00000000
00000000
00000000
01000000
00100000
N0000000
```

How can I "convert" it into a move or "apply" that move?

Answer (score 2):

There are actually two questions in your post

- **How to convert Attacks in Bitboards to a list of moves?**
- **How to represent those moves?**

---

> - **How to represent those moves?**

This question has been discussed [here](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/9706/representing-moves-found-via-bitboards-applying-them-and-removing-them) and [here](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/18017/whats-the-right-approach-of-storing-moves-generated-using-bitboards) thoroughly. But to provide some context to the readers of this post, a very simple way to do this can be to use a class / struct to represent a move

- **From** ( where the moving piece was )
- **To**   ( where the moving piece will be )
- **Special Move Flag**  ( whether the move was a special move, i.e enpassant, casting, promotion)
- **Promoted Piece** ( if the move was a promotion move, what piece did it promote to )

You can also have extra attributes such as captured piece, type of castle etc. But that information can also be deduced using the `From` and `To` squares.

So considering the above, we can represent the move as follows

```
struct Move {
    char from; 
    char to;   
    char spMoveFlag;
    char promotedPiece;
};
```

However, a lot of chess engines, including mine use another method that can compress the move into just `16` bits. Read more about that [here](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/18017/whats-the-right-approach-of-storing-moves-generated-using-bitboards).

Once we know what a move is, we can answer the next question

---

> - **How to convert Attacks in Bitboards to a list of moves?**

Let's consider that we have a **knight** on the square **d4**. We also have a function that returns the attacks of a knight given the square.

```
. . . . . . . . 
. . . . . . . . 
. . 1 . 1 . . . 
. 1 . . . 1 . . 
. . . n . . . .   =  knightattacks(SQ_D4)
. 1 . . . 1 . . 
. . 1 . 1 . . . 
. . . . . . . .
```

So let's store this inside a variable `knightAttacks`

```
uint64_t knightAttacks = getKnightAttacksBB(SQ_D4);
```

If you notice carefully we already have 1 of the 4 attributes we need to represent the move, which is the `From` square - `D4`. Now all we need to do is somehow get the `To` square to complete this since a knight cannot perform any kind of special moves.

A very common method is to [pop the least significant bit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/757059/position-of-least-significant-bit-that-is-set) until your `knightAttacks` is left with nothing i.e `0`.

```
0000011100001000 
            ^
            Least significant bit (lsb)
```

You can follow the link I provided to know how you can perform this, or there is a chance that [your compiler might already provide you with it.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intrinsic_function)

You simply need to create a function that clears the lsb of a bitboard and returns its index. Let's call it `poplsb()`.

Altogether, your code can look like this

```
int from = SQ_D4;
uint16_t knightAttacks = getknightAttacks(from);

while (knightAttacks)  {
     int to = poplsb(knightAttacks);
     MyMoveList.Add( NewMove(from, to, 0, 0) ); // The last two 0's denote that there is no special move
}
```

This works because each time you pop the lsb, a bit gets cleared until the number is == 0. That's when the loop stops and you have a perfectly good list of moves. The same idea applies to any kind of moves you have created using Bitboards.